# Connect PostgreSQL server running in docker container to wild-fly docker container?

Tags: postgresql, docker, wildfly, dockerfile

I am not able to connect wild-fly container to PostgreSQL server which is running in different container. But, I am able to connect to database from host machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [networking](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/dockernetworks/) and [links](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/dockerlinks/). I Would recommend networking. The name of the container inside a network can resolved by the dns to the netwok intern IP adress. E.g. jdbc:mysql://db_container_name:3306/